# Table order messed in Firefox, but works fine in other browsers

Tags: python, html, django, firefox, django-templates

I have a table that I sort by date, it works fine in EDGE and Chrome, but the order is messed in Firefox. A series of rows that should be on top got moved down to the bottom.
HTML:

```
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <h6 class="card-header">Change Log Items</h6>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table id="changes" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-sm">
                    <thead class="table-dark">
                        <tr class="sticky">
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Component</th>
                            <th>Date Committed</th>
                            <th>Jira Link</th>
                            <th>Details</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for log in logs %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{log.title}}</td>
                            <td>{{log.component}}</td>
                            <td>{{log.date_added}}</td>
                            <td>{% if log.jira_number %}<a class="general" href="https://jira.kinaxis.com/browse/{{log.jira_number}}" target="_blank">{{log.jira_number}}{% endif %}</a></td>
                            <td>{% if log.details %}{{log.details}}{% elif not log.details and log.jira_number %}See Jira ticket{% endif %}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View:

```
@login_required
def change_log(request):
    logs = ChangeLog.objects.all().order_by('date_added')
    return render(request, 'help\changelog.html', {'logs': logs})
```

Any information helps! :)

Update:
I realized the problem was caused by the jQuery corresponding to the HTML element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    const exceptions = $('#changes').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        "pageLength": 50,
        "columnDefs": [{"type": "date", "targets": [2],}], // Sort by Date properly
    });
});
</script>
```

Seems like DataTable has some issues with FF?
Changing the order in "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]" to asc doesn't work for FF.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I have updated my post, it was because of the Datatable plug-in I use, but still have not found a way to solve it

Comment: Can you provide sample values (and valid HTML, since the issue is not with Django templates) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: What's the date format looking like in your template?  DataTables struggles to sort certain formats correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the date format you are using is not supported by Firefox, as *"the date formats supported by each browser vary significantly"*. In such cases, one could use the "ultimate" date / time ordering plug-in for DataTables, as suggested [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18). To do that, include the following libraries in your HTML file, as described in the above link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.5/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

Next, register the date format(s) that you wish DataTables to detect and order using the `$.fn.dataTable.moment(format)` method. For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'HH:mm MMM D, YY' );
    ...
```

DataTables will automatically detect the column(s) with date data, by checking to see if the data in a column matches any of the given types. You can register multiple date formats, if a DataTable contains more than one date columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly adding "ordering: true" to your DataTable() instantiation, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    const exceptions = $('#changes').DataTable({
        ordering: true, # add this line
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        "pageLength": 50,
        "columnDefs": [{"type": "date", "targets": [2],}], // Sort by Date properly
    });
});
</script>
```

More a suggestion than an answer, but didn't want to paste this code in the comments.